# cordova-plugin-camera fails to retrieve file

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, ngcordova

So cordova-plugin-camera fails each time getPicture is called with exception 'Error retrieving image'. I dug a bit, and it seems like I am not the only one with this issue, and there is even a [pull request](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera/pull/160), that I thought might be relevant. I tried hardcoding the pull request into plugin, but it still didn't work, error changed to  **Error modifying image**. Here is the stacktrace:

```
E/Vold    ( 2319): Failed to find mounted volume for /storage/extSdCard/Android/data/com.sec.android.gallery3d/cache/
W/Vold    ( 2319): Returning OperationFailed - no handler for errno 0
W/ContextImpl(13028): Failed to ensure directory: /storage/extSdCard/Android/data/com.sec.android.gallery3d/cache
I/Gallery_Performance(13028): Gallery onDestroy End
D/MapViewPage(13028): onDetachedFromWindow():
D/MultiPhoneWindow(13028): performUpdateVisibility : visible :false
E/ActivityThread(13028): Activity com.sec.android.gallery3d.app.Gallery has leaked IntentReceiver com.sec.android.gallery3d.app.GalleryCoverMode$2@1090fb5b that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
E/ActivityThread(13028): android.app.IntentReceiverLeaked: Activity com.sec.android.gallery3d.app.Gallery has leaked IntentReceiver com.sec.android.gallery3d.app.GalleryCoverMode$2@1090fb5b that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
E/ActivityThread(13028):        at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:960)
E/ActivityThread(13028):        at android.app.LoadedApk.getReceiverDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:761)
E/ActivityThread(13028):        at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiverInternal(ContextImpl.java:2002)
E/ActivityThread(13028):        at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:1982)
E/ActivityThread(13028):        at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:1976)
E/ActivityThread(13028):        at android.content.ContextWrapper.registerReceiver(ContextWrapper.java:503)
E/ActivityThread(13028):        at com.sec.android.gallery3d.app.GalleryCoverMode.registerReceiverGlobal(GalleryCoverMode.java:265)
E/ActivityThread(13028):        at com.sec.android.gallery3d.app.GalleryCoverMode.setCoverMode(GalleryCoverMode.java:72)
E/ActivityThread(13028):        at com.sec.android.gallery3d.app.GalleryCoverMode.<init>(GalleryCoverMode.java:68)
E/ActivityThread(13028):        at com.sec.android.gallery3d.app.Gallery.initialize(Gallery.java:351)
E/ActivityThread(13028):        at com.sec.android.gallery3d.app.Gallery$6.handleMessage(Gallery.java:1378)
E/ActivityThread(13028):        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
E/ActivityThread(13028):        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
E/ActivityThread(13028):        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5942)
E/ActivityThread(13028):        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/ActivityThread(13028):        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
E/ActivityThread(13028):        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1400)
E/ActivityThread(13028):        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1195)
E/Vold    ( 2319): Failed to find mounted volume for /storage/extSdCard/Android/data/com.appName.app/cache/
W/Vold    ( 2319): Returning OperationFailed - no handler for errno 0
W/ContextImpl( 9583): Failed to ensure directory: /storage/extSdCard/Android/data/com.appName.app/cache
W/System.err( 9583): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.appName.app/cache: open failed: EISDIR (Is a directory)
W/System.err( 9583):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:456)
W/System.err( 9583):    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:87)
W/System.err( 9583):    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:127)
W/System.err( 9583):    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:116)
W/System.err( 9583):    at org.apache.cordova.camera.CameraLauncher.ouputModifiedBitmap(CameraLauncher.java:576)
W/System.err( 9583):    at org.apache.cordova.camera.CameraLauncher.processResultFromGallery(CameraLauncher.java:684)
W/System.err( 9583):    at org.apache.cordova.camera.CameraLauncher.access$000(CameraLauncher.java:66)
W/System.err( 9583):    at org.apache.cordova.camera.CameraLauncher$1.run(CameraLauncher.java:787)
W/System.err( 9583):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
W/System.err( 9583):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
W/System.err( 9583):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
W/System.err( 9583): Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: EISDIR (Is a directory)
W/System.err( 9583):    at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
W/System.err( 9583):    at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:186)
W/System.err( 9583):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:442)
W/System.err( 9583):    ... 10 more
I/chromium( 9583): [INFO:CONSOLE(123)] "Failed because: Error modifying image.", source: file:///android_asset/www/js/directives/cameraHandler.js (123)
```

And the code causing this:

```
var opts = {
  quality: 50,
  destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
  sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.SAVEDPHOTOALBUM,
  correctOrientation: true,
  targetWidth: 680,
  targetHeight: 480
};
navigator.camera.getPicture(function(res) {
  console.log('Success');
}, function(error) {
  console.log('Failed because: ' + error);
}, opts);
```

I am not very familiar with android development, but it seems like it tries to read a directory as a file. Any ideas how to fix it ?

Comment: Please include the code and stacktrace in your question rather than externally

Comment: there was a bug on the camera plugin. It was partially fixed on current released version and totally fixed on the version on github. Update the plugin and try again.